# Changing duplicate $scope array but it's affecting original ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that is cycling through `$scope.myarray`.

I have the following function:

```
var copy = $scope.myarray;

$.each(copy, function(index, data){
    data.name = "";
});
```

When I do this, it seems to be affecting my `ng-repeat` loop on `$scope.myarray`.

When I do:

```
console.log(copy);
console.log($scope.myarray);
```

They both seem to have the `$$hashKey` so I am thinking that is what is screwing things up.

What is the best way to manipulate my copy of the array without affecting the first version?

Comment: Why are you iterating over the array?  Can you get away with making a copy with `angular.copy` and manipulating it separately?

Comment: I'm doing conditional checks on each item in the array, just didn't show it in my example @anied

Comment: Your code doesn't show conditional checks, it shows you making changes on items in the array...

Comment: Like I said, I'm just not showing it in my example. It had nothing to do with my question. `angular.copy` did not bring the $$hashkey over, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to copy you should use

```
var copy = angular.copy($scope.myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing this:

```
var copy = $scope.myarray;
```

You are not creating a copy of $scope.myarray but you are just assigning the reference to $scope.myarray to a new variable.

so doing:

```
$.each(copy, function(index, data){
    data.name = "";
});
```

is exactly the same as

```
$.each($scope.myarray, function(index, data){
    data.name = "";
});
```

You need to copy all the items of the $scope.myarray to a new array ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486130))

Depending on what kind of data you have in $scope.myarray, you might have to do a deep copy/cloning